# iOS This app is currently not available in your country or region

Tags: ios

My app is not found in App Store , by showing alert "This app is currently not available in your country or region".

Answer (score 1):

Verify if in Pricing and Availability the app's Availability is set for all coutries or regions.

If is not, you can set for a specify range of countries or regions or all countries and regions.